# How to make Windows maximize act like Mac OS X

Tags: windows, macos

In Windows the maximize button maximizes the window.
In Mac OS X the "maximize" button zooms on the window - makes the window size fit the document size. How do I make (using a 3rd party software I guess) Windows windows act like the ones on Mac OS X?

I googled and searched, but found only people asking how to make Mac OS X maximize to act like Windows' (i.e. [How to maximize application on entire screen in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/23961/how-to-maximize-application-on-entire-screen-in-mac-os-x)). I would like the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite mac like but you can give it a try -> http://tovilevis.com/index.php?cat=development&sub=programs&id=7